# Image from MySql with Nodejs coming in buffer array

Tags: mysql, node.js, buffer

Please help me with the following problem.

I already saved some images in my database in a column with type blod (images are .png). Now I want to make a request (I'm using for tests the program POSTMAN) but I'm getting in Json one type buffer array with some numbers inside.

How can I get the image to show it wherever I want?

```js
app.get('/getCountries', (req, res) => {

  const queryString = "SELECT name,flag_png,info FROM countries"

  getConnection().query(queryString, (err, results, fields) => { <br/>
    if(err){<br/>
      console.log('Failed to get request' + err);<br/>
      res.sendStatus(500);<br/>
    }else{<br/>
      console.log('The get request succesfully');<br/>
      res.json(results);<br/>
      //res.end()<br/>
    }<br/>
  })<br/>
})<br/>
```

Also I'm thinking now maybe it's not a good idea to save images in db base and it's better idea to save it in server. What is your opinion on this ?

Comment: Show your route and how you make request to it

Comment: This is my get request at my API. 

app.get('/getCountries', (req, res) => {

  const queryString = "SELECT name,flag_png,info FROM countries"

  getConnection().query(queryString, (err, results, fields) => {
    if(err){
      console.log('Failed to get request' + err);
      res.sendStatus(500);
    }else{
      console.log('The get request succesfully');
      res.json(results);
      //res.end()
    }
  })
})

Comment: Please add then to your post with a proper formatting. It's hard to read code in comments

Comment: I added. Thank you!

Comment: If i am correct, the mysql driver automatically parses it into a buffer. Instead of sending results, set content type to image/png and send the image alone. Otherwise you have to manually convert the array buffer to base64 in your frontend to get the image back i guess.

Comment: @t348575 I'm trying to convert it the buffer URL to base64 but I'm not getting back some path or something understandable instead I'm getting many many characters. How i can do the first option you said? 

Also I'm thinking because many people saying that to save images in database is terrible idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing images in a database is not recommended unless the number of images is relatively small (Because database performance drops as the size of a row increases and the number of rows increase). If you have a huge number of images, it's much better to store on your filesystem and expose an API for a webpage to access the image, where you retrieve a list of URL's to the image from your database.

### Includes

```js
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const logger = require('morgan');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
const url = require('url');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const localPool = mysql.createPool({
    host: 'some_host',
    user: 'some_user',
    password: 'some_password',
    database: 'some_database'
});
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

### Code to get images by an image ID stored in the database

```js
// to get image ID's
app.get('/getCountries', (req, res) => {
    // return multiple results
    const queryString = 'SELECT name,flag,info FROM countries WHERE some_expression';
    localPool.query(queryString, (err, results) => {
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).end();
          } else if (results.length === 0) {
            res.status(404).end();
          } else {
              // note here I have a field called flag which contains and "ID" for the image.
            res.json(results);
          }
    });
});
// to get the image by the ID 
app.get('/getImage', (req, res) => {
    // get image id from url like: /getImage?id=91238129537
    const id = (url.parse(req.url, true).query).id;
    fs.readFile(path.resolve(`someDirectory/${id}`), { flag: 'r' }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).end();
        } else {
            res.set('Content-Type', 'image');
            res.end(data, 'binary');
        }
    });
});
```

### Code to return an image from your database

```js
app.get('/getCountries', (req, res) => {
     // use LIMIT or WHERE to avoid a large set of results
    const queryString = "SELECT name,flag_png,info FROM countries WHERE some_expression LIMIT 1";
    localPool.query(queryString, (err, results) => {
      if(err) {
        res.status(500).end();
      } else if (results.length === 0) {
        res.status(404).end();
      } else {
        res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
        res.end(results[0].flag_png, 'binary');
      }
    })
});
const server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your big explain reply. Yes i have many images and i will have more in the future. So the better way to do this is to save the images inside at one file in my API or at different file ?

Comment: I dont understand your question. Store the images in a folder, and store the names of those image files in the database. That is the suggested method. Use express.static() to serve the images without an api route if you want, since express.static() already has caching.

Comment: Ok.. So storing the name of image as text in database and the image in your file system. Thank you very much!